# CSS button not clickable on left

Tags: css, button

I have been 75% successful by looking at this post: [How Do I Make a CSS Button Clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530022/how-do-i-make-a-css-button-clickable)

But still if the cursor comes in on the left the button is not clickable.

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.christianfordlive.com/buy-tickets/"><span class="buy">Buy Tickets Now</span></a>
```

**CSS**

```
 .buy {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 27px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -70px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: Calibri,Helvetica, sans serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #39b54a;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px;

}
.buy:hover {
  background-color: #8dc63f;
}
```

Could someone help with what I got wrong?
http://christianfordlive.com

Comment: What happens if you don't use a negative left margin?

Comment: Remove the `z-index` value you have in your `#mainImage` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is generated by the div **mainImage** and the **left margin**. The div mainPage is in front of your button, that's why you can't click on it.

You have two easy options to fix the bug:

1 - Remove the margin-left of your button

```
margin-left: 0px;
```

If you do it, the div mainImage will stop overlapping your span.

You can also modify the z-index of your button to force it to go to the front of the mainImage div. For example, just add it to your .buy class:

```
z-index: 1000;
```

Both options should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is kind of a mess, and you are overruling properties inside the same rule.  All you need is:

html:

```
<a class="buy" href="http://www.christianfordlive.com/buy-tickets/">Buy Tickets Now</a>
```

css:

```
.buy {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Calibri,Helvetica, sans serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #39b54a;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```